# Mysqli always returns connection success

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

On all of my php pages I include the follow db connection code

```
<?php
$dbInfo = parse_ini_file('path/to/ini/file');
define ("HOST", $dbInfo["HOST"]); // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", $dbInfo["USER"]); // The database username.
define("PASSWORD", $dbInfo["PASSWORD"]); // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", $dbInfo["DATABASE"]); // The database name.

  $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
// If you are connecting via TCP/IP rather than a UNIX socket remember to add the port number as a parameter.
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('fail');
} else {
  echo 'success';
}


If ((USER == "USERNAME HERE") || (PASSWORD == "PASSWORD HERE")){
  print 'ERROR - Please set up the script first';
    exit();
}
?>
```

No matter what I do (such as putting in the wrong password or putting the path to the file wrong), it always echo's "success".  I've tried using a try/catch for the error, putting an @ in front of new mysqli, using the object oriented If($mysqli->connect_error).  Nothing I do will return fail

When I put

```
echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```

instead of echo success, I get

```
Success... Localhost via UNIX socket
```

can anyone tell me why I keep getting this bogus success message? 
Edit:  What I'm looking for in the end is not every php error message such as I use for development (i.e. ini_set('display_errors',1);), but just the single "fail" message I've placed within the If connection_error statement.

Edit2: Result of var_dump($mysqli); using a bad file path (parse_ini_file points to location with no file)

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(6) "5.5.32" ["client_version"]=> int(50532) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(23) "5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.10.1" ["server_version"]=> int(50532) ["stat"]=> string(135) "Uptime: 8944 Threads: 1 Questions: 2445 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 275 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 67 Queries per second avg: 0.273" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(468) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }
```

And the result of var_dump(mysqli_connect_error());

```
NULL
```

The result of var_dump($mysqli); using the correct file path (tested and verified)

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(6) "5.5.32" ["client_version"]=> int(50532) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(23) "5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.10.1" ["server_version"]=> int(50532) ["stat"]=> string(136) "Uptime: 15306 Threads: 1 Questions: 2446 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 275 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 67 Queries per second avg: 0.159" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(471) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }

NULL
```

As you can see, the result of both var_dumps are identical (except for the uptime) regardless of if I have the correct path typed into parse_ini_file or if I've pointed it to a bogus location where no file exists.

Edit 3: The question has been answered, look in the comments until enough time has passed for me to answer my own question.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turn on? For a development environment, set: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: If I set ini_set('display_errors',1); then it will tell me that it can't open the file, but I'll still get a successful connection message.  I'll edit my question to clarify that what I want is for there to be a connection error message displayed to the user if something goes wrong, but I don't want every php hiccup displayed on the screen.

Comment: I said 'development environment'. Right now, you are developing, so you need the error messages to debug.

Comment: I've added your code and like I said, it gives me the error message that the file doesn't exist (I've deliberately misspelled it), but then I still get a successful connection message.  The issue I need help with isn't displaying all error messages, just finding out why my single error message is not displaying (and turning on display_errors does not provide any information on that matter)

Comment: @Abishur - `var_dump` is your friend. Try `var_dump($mysqli)` after you try to connect; what does it return? Set the return value of `mysqli_connect_error()` to a string, and `var_dump()` that, too.

Comment: @andrewsi Var dump returns the same information when I try to connect to it with the wrong path and the correct path, specifically for "Connect_error" both read => NULL, "errno"=> int(0), and "connect_errno"=>int(0)

Comment: @Abishur - Sorry, I don't follow what you mean. Could you edit it into your question, and cut and paste the exact values that you're seeing from `var_dump($mysqli)` and `var_dump(mysqli_connect_error())`, with a working and invalid connection?

Comment: while I don't mind the down votes, I would greatly appreciate some comments from those down voting it on how I might improve the question

Comment: There are no bogus messages. You need to learn to trust your eyes. The output you have clearly says that mysqli successfully connected. So, *you* need to try harder making it fail.

Comment: @common sense, I'm pointing it to a file which does not exist, how can it be successfully connecting without defined variables?  Is it seeing that a database exists on localhost and calling it success without connecting to anything?

Comment: You need to learn to trust your eyes. That's all I could say.

Comment: Okay, I'll trust my eyes, I am successfully connected to a database, looking at the documentation, when Nulls are provided it does indeed assume localhost and tries to connect with any user who has no password specified.  So how can find out who it thinks it's connecting as and to what database?

Comment: @common, can you write your initial statement as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: You can write an answer yourself. As of connection parameters - it takes them from php.ini I believe.

Comment: I will write out the answer in another 4 hours when I'm allowed to (I don't have enough rep yet), but the long and short is mysql installs 3 global access users with use privileges that require no password.  Deleting these three users did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to user "Your Common Sense" for point me in the right direction.

According to the documentation on the mysqli construct http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php when host is NULL or undefined it defaults to localhost, when password is NULL or undefined

> "the MySQL server will attempt to authenticate the user against those user records which have no password only."

So whenever I pointed to a bogus file location, it attempted to connect to the localhost with any username that accepted no passwords.  Unfortunately, Mysql installs three users with global access and no password (Usage privileges only) by default.  Resulting in my bogus file location gaining a successful connection.

The solution was to drop those three users (and the test database).  I now get a fail using any number of the previously mentioned methods including

```
if (NULL !== mysqli_connect_error()) { 
  die('fail'); 
} else {
  echo 'success';
}
```

or

```
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('fail');
} else {
  echo 'success';
}
```

or

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know the answer, but now I have read your problem and I think it's good question. For me at least :) Thanks :)